# problem to select specific data from tables

Tags: php, sql

i want to get specific data from 3 tables i have in my database but my sql query is kinda wrong ,
i have a "com" varaible sent to get id of my publication
my db looks like :
- comments:id,com,idpub,iduser
-pub:id,publication,iduser
-users:id,username

```
SELECT username ,publication.id,publication.publication,publication.iduser ,comments.com,comments.idpub 
FROM users,pub,comments 
where publication.id=".$_GET['com'] ." and users.id=publication.iduser and comments.idpub=publication.id
```

with this query i want to get username publication.com (com belongs to that publication)

Comment: Have you heard of `JOIN`?  Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try groupby in your SQL.

```
SELECT username ,publication.id,publication.publication,publication.iduser,comments.com,comments.idpub
FROM users,pub,comments
where publication.id=".$_GET['com'] ." and users.id=publication.iduser and comments.idpub=publication.id
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: @yolo . . . This query is broken.  The `group by` and `select` columns are inconsistent.  In most databases -- including more recent versions of MySQL -- it would generate an error.  If it works, that is only because it *seems* to work, not because it is correct.